# Manipulate the Height when binding with relative resource in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I have a tree view and want to set the `height` = *the height of the window -120*.

I tried this but it does not work. Could you help me out?

thanks,

Jang.

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding  NavigationData}" 
    Height="{Binding Path=Height -120, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type  Window}}}" >
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a converter.

Create a converter

```
public class HeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
      object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
     {
        return ((int) value) - 120;
     }
}
```

Add the converter to resources

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <local:HeightConverter x:Key="myConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Set the converter in your binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding NavigationData}" Height="{Binding Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Binding` does not support logic in the `Path` as you have above in your example (-120).  Depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you may be able to use the `VerticalAlignment` (set it to `Stretch`) and the `Margin`.

```
<TreeView VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,60,0,60"/>
```

Otherwise, if you need to data bind, you can use a `Converter` that subtracts a value from the value that is passed in.